# plv8 stored procedure with jsonb type

Tags: postgresql, plv8, postgresql-9.4

This may be premature, postgres 9.4 is still in beta.  I've been experimenting with the jsonb type.  I am not having any luck passing a jsonb type to a plv8 function, it comes in as type string.  I was wondering if I was doing it wrong?

```
create or replace function jt ( o json ) returns integer language plv8 immutable
AS $function$
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'type is ', typeof o);
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'argument is ', o);
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'member is ', o['member']);
$function$;

create or replace function jt ( o jsonb ) returns integer language plv8 immutable
AS $function$
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'type is ', typeof o);
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'argument is ', o);
        plv8.elog(INFO, 'member is ', o['member']);
$function$;
```

then, when I run using json:

```
psql=# select jt('{"member":"test"}'::json);
INFO:  type is  object
INFO:  argument is  [object Object]
INFO:  member is  test
```

but, when I run with jsonb:

```
psql=# select jt('{"member":"test"}'::jsonb);
INFO:  type is  string
INFO:  argument is  {"member": "test"}
INFO:  member is  undefined
```

-g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PL/V8 will need to add support for JSONB before this works how you expect.

In the mean time you can still pass plain `json`; just cast the `jsonb` to `json`.

### News since ~2015

*plv8 project* changed after 2014, as [this comment of the project's sponsor and main contributor, JerrySievert](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/224#issuecomment-532079410), in 2017:

> the JSONB vs JSON speed differences were well known and addressed,
>
> JSONB now does a direct conversion in C++ into v8 objects and runs faster than a JSON conversion

The [last revision history](https://api.pgxn.org/src/plv8/plv8-2.3.11/Changes) show some clues about JSONb starting date:

- in 2015-05-26 (version 1.4.4 ) *"Add jsonb type coercion in function boundary"*.
- in 2019-03-23 (version 2.3.10)  *"add direct jsonb conversion option", "add memory context for jsonb conversion"*.

The suggestion is to use JSONB with plv8 version  2.3.10 or later... Still, for older versions of plv8,  [Jarry confirmed](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/402#issuecomment-668099671) that almost everything will be fine:

> JSONB support has been active and complete since April 22, 2015.

Comment: Hi, please update... Or [check if it was really updated](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/402#issuecomment-667599822).

Comment: @PeterKrauss Please propose an edit with the information you want shown. I can't keep track of everything. Note the 2014 answer date.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I uninstalled plv8, no way to check empirical evidence... I am editing your question with the news. Comment **for other readers**: please check (by performance) that it is really JSONb  input, not a syntax sugar (automatic cast `JSONb::text`).

Comment: @PeterKrauss  Thanks very much, appreciated.